# Visual Studio Emulator cannot start whitout internet? Exit Code 10

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-10, visual-studio-emulator

I have a strange problem, the VS Emulator starts normally if the internet is active, but without, it gives me this error:

> 17/10/2015 18:56:12: [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 17 Platforms: 2
>   17/10/2015 18:56:15: [Informational] Waiting to launch device...
>   17/10/2015 18:56:15: [Informational] Launching Device: 4.5" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Phone
>   17/10/2015 18:56:15: [Informational] Validating emulator arguments...
>   17/10/2015 18:56:15: [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running...
>   17/10/2015 18:56:15: [Informational] Preparing virtual machine...
>   17/10/2015 18:56:18: [Informational] Launching emulator...
>   17/10/2015 18:57:30: [Critical] Could not launch 'VS Emulator 4.5" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Phone' device. Exit code 10.
>   17/10/2015 18:57:30: [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\xde.exe
>   17/10/2015 18:57:30: [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 4.5\" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Phone" /memSize 1024 /diagonalSize 4.5 /video "720x1280" /vhd "C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\4.5_Lollipop_(5.1.1)_XHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 4.5-inch Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Phone.fabio"
>   17/10/2015 18:57:30: [Critical] XDE Exit Code: CouldntStartVm (10)

[The emulator has not verified if the VM is in execution: this host is unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umeHg.png)

Anybody knows the solution? I don't have internet always.
Thanks.